# Web API authentication for public/private URL using Azure AD

Tags: azure, authentication, webapi

We are doing a POC for urn redirect from web API. we categorized the URL as public and private. we have a requirement if the url is public, just redirect from web API which is working fine.

if the URL is private (contains company domain name in the URL) we need to check for the authentication. we are planning to use Azure AD JWT to do this.

Can someone please tell me how to redirect from web API to authenticate user and once successfully authenticated we need to redirect from web API to the private URL.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a WebAPI is invoked behind the scenes. Why do you want to redirect something?

Your client will/should send the Authorization header with the bearer token in the request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration